# Can't use Acro Package, .sty stored in appdata\

Tags: miktex, texstudio, acro

I wanted to manage my acronyms with the acro package, because it lists them in alphabetical order. However, everytime i try to compile, it gives me a bunch of these errors.

```
Zeile 447: LaTeX error: "kernel/property-unknown" The key property '.value_required:n' is unknown. For immediate help type H <return>. }
```

I use miktex and tried installing it by mentioning it in my document, which seemed to work. The log shows however, that the file is located in C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\acro\acro.sty, or moreover, it was only installed there, the miktex package manager didn't even mention it.
I then tried to install it with the package manager, but texstudio proceeds to only use the files in appdata.
The Package author answered me on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues), that me l3kernel is outdated, tried updating it via the package manager, but texstudio proceeds to use packages it got under appdata....

How can i force texstudio to use the (succesfully installed) acro package in program files (x86)\miktex 2.9\tex\latex\acro and to install packages there in the future?
I never had this problem before with any package and didnt change any of the standard settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to missing updates to essential packages, solved with a software update

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to kind of hotfix this by

- installing all relevant packages via the package manager
- updating all packages
- copying the updated packages to the appdata\miktex directory

Now compiling works, but I'm not exactly satisfied with this solution.